# Difference pip/pipenv

Tags: django, pip, pipenv

I guess it's going to be obvious in a few seconds but I am fairly new to web development.

I am learning how to use Django and I encountered an issue with `allauth` after having installed it through `pipenv` and tried to migrate. I got a lovely `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'`. As I said, I installed it through `pipenv` and I could see `allauth` in my `.venv/Lib/site-packages` file. I have my virtual environment set and activated.

A quick research and thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023833/16358858), I solved my issue by "reinstalling" it with `pip install allauth`, and my migration is now working fine.

What I don't understand is, wasn't it already installed when I did `pipenv install allauth`, do I need to install everything once with `pipenv` to get the `Pipfile` & `Pipfile.lock` updated and then also install it through `pip`...?

Obviously, I don't fully understand the difference between `pipenv` & `pip`, if some charitable soul would be kind enough to explain this to me, I'd greatly appreciate it :)

Edit: I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197692/) already but either way I am stupid or whatever but it still doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

so, you said `pip install allauth` fixed the issue for you. But that might be because it installed the package GLOBALLY, and you definitely don't wanna do that.

Rather, you should try reinstalling using `pipenv` itself. It has happened to me before and got fixed this way.

In case if that didn't work, try removing and re-setuping the virtual env -

`pipenv --rm`
`pipenv shell`
`pipenv install`

#### Difference between PIP & PIPENV

In a very layman's language,

**pip** is a package installing manager itself used to install other packages like panda, pillow, django, virtualenv... etc

**pipenv**, on the other hand, is a package created to simplifies the burden of using `virtualenv` and `pip` seperately. (I'm assuming you know how `virtualenv` works)

You don't need `pipenv` if you are using `virtualenv` with `pip`. But I would anyday recommend to use `pipenv` because who wants pain right?

To understand more, I think you should also research (google) **VIRTUALENV vs PIPENV**. That'll definitely help.

Reference URL
[https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/#:~:text=You%20no%20longer%20need%20to%20use%20pip%20and%20virtualenv%20separately.%20They%20work%20together](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/#:%7E:text=You%20no%20longer%20need%20to%20use%20pip%20and%20virtualenv%20separately.%20They%20work%20together)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering :) 
I used `pip install allauth` with my venv activated so, if I got it right... it can't have installed it globally, can it? Can I verify that?  Thanks for your Google search suggestion, I did check pip/pipenv but not virtualenv/pipenv. It has lead me to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/) which was a good source of info :)